# Assign SQL result to shell variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, db2

I am trying to assign the result of the db2 command to a variable inside a shell script:

```
backup_end_time="$(db2 select END_TIME FROM SYSIBMADM.DB_HISTORY where operation = "'B'" AND OBJECTTYPE = "'D'" ORDER BY START_TIME DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY | awk 'NR==4')"

echo $backup_end_time
```

When I echo I am getting a blank value. I am expecting value `20191113030053`.

If I try the same command outside the script without assigning to variable

```
db2 select END_TIME FROM SYSIBMADM.DB_HISTORY where operation = "'B'" AND OBJECTTYPE = "'D'" ORDER BY START_TIME DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY | awk 'NR==4'
```

I get the expected output.

How can I assign the output to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the quotes correct and also use the -x option to the CLP to avoid needing to awk the output.

Example:

```
backup_end_time=$(db2 -x "select END_TIME FROM SYSIBMADM.DB_HISTORY where operation = 'B' AND OBJECTTYPE = 'D' ORDER BY START_TIME DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash opens sub-shell too often.
When you call `v=$(db2 ...)`, then a new sub-shell is opened, and db2 front-end process doesn't have a connection to a db2 background process (db2bp) opened for your current shell.

```
#db2 "select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1" | awk 'NR==4' | read v

tmpf=f.txt
db2 "select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1" | awk 'NR==4' > ${tmpf}
read -r v < ${tmpf}
rm -f ${tmpf}
echo "Value: ${v}"
```

Commented out line works with ksh, but not with bash.